# Checking if an XML element is marked with `xsi:nil` in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I am working on a stored procedure which shreds an XML document. One of the child elements in the records being processed can sometimes be marked with the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute. Other times, it can contain a `dateTime`. I'm trying to insert a string into a column of my table which depends on whether or not this element has a value. For example:

```
[Status] = CASE WHEN (Rt.Item.value('(./Date)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = '') THEN N'SUBMITTED' ELSE N'PROCESSED' END
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working. What's the correct to check if an element has a value in SQL Server?

Comment: Are you asking about exists? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx

Comment: I don't *think* so. The element is always there, but sometimes it has the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute, and other times it has a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Generally**:

```
theElementName[not(@xsi:nil eq 'true')]/any/other/needed/location/steps
```

If the association of the `"xsi"` prefix to the appropriate namespace isn't registered (the way to do this is implementation-specific and you need to check how this is to be done in your situation), one still can use:

```
theElementName[not(@*[name() eq 'xsi:nil'] eq 'true')]
```